# Trigger to add Salutation in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

In the Salesforce account object, I have the field Gender that has 3 values- Male, Female, and None. I have to write a trigger to update the Name field with the prefix Mr, Mrs based on gender value change. I have written the below trigger. It is working fine on before insert but not working for before update as I am unable to write the logic.

Trigger code-

```
trigger PrefixAdd on Account (before insert, before update) {
   
    For(Account Acc : trigger.new) 
    {
             
        if(Trigger.isupdate && trigger.isbefore){
            
            if (Acc.label__Gender__c != trigger.oldMap.get(Acc.Id).label__Gender__c)
            { 
                String S= Acc.Name;
                
                if(Acc.label__Gender__c=='Male') {
                    
                    String S1= S.removeStart('Mr.');
                    Acc.Name = 'Mrs.' + S1;
                    
                }
                
                if(Acc.label__Gender__c=='Female'){
                    
                    String S2= S.removeStart('Mrs.');
                    Acc.Name = 'Mr.' + S2;  
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is misguided on a number of levels. It's not clear why you're using Accounts, instead of either Contacts or Person Accounts which have proper fields for personal names and include a salutation field. You're enforcing a title and gender structure that will offend a huge number of people - doctors, academics, clergy, military, unmarried women, women who prefer 'Ms.', and persons who do not identify as male or female. You should reconsider this whole project.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I got the requirement like this. Could please help me to write the before update trigger.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to be very specific about the problem (you _have_ written before update code here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far more complicated than it needs to be. Here's a revised version:

```
trigger prefixAdd on Account (before insert, before update) {
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    String salutation = '';
    switch on (record.Label_Gender__c) {
      when 'Male' { salutation = 'Mr. '; }
      when 'Female' { salutation = 'Mrs. '; }
    }
    record.Name = salutation+record.Name.removeStart('Mr. ').removeStart('Mrs. ');
  }
}
```

The reason why we don't use any if statements is because they are superfluous. The trigger context is already always either before insert or before update, so we don't need to check those flags, and the operation is "harmless" if the gender hasn't changed, so there's no point in *not* recalculating the salutation.

There's some oddities if someone enters in some intentionally odd names, like 'Mr. Mrs. Mr. Awkward Name', but as a general use case, this code above should work in normal situations.